# how to remember user name and password in django

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

I want to prepopulate a user's user name and password at login like this:

[image]

I'm pretty sure I wouldn't save the password to a cookie.

How else would I accomplish this?

Comment: I think the screenshot you provided is being populated by your browser, which you chose to save your username and password yourself when prompted. It's not something done from your end.

Comment: it is browser's job since browser company clarified the privacy issues. you better dont do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you *really, really* don't want to do this. There is absolutely no good reason to prepopulate a user's password field

Of course, you can keep them logged in for as long as you like, that's simply a matter of setting the session expiry. But what would be the benefit of prepopulating their password? Just don't do it.